# Injecting params into template URL

Tags: angularjs, url, parameters

You can write a router in angularjs with the instruction `.when("/resource/:id")` and then access the `id` via `$routeParams.id`.

However, how would I have to go if I had this 'parameterized' url as a template, and then wanted to inject 'id' into id. What I'm looking for is a method that looks like this:

```
$url.inject("/resource/:id", { id: 3 }) // => "/resource/3"
```

Also, we are using the `ui-router` library, so if there's no way in angular, is there a way in ui-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking inside ui-router's source, I noticed that there is a UrlMatcher. I simply had to inject a $urlMatcherFactory with which I could easily accomplish what I wanted:

```
$urlMatcherFactory.compile("/resource/:id").format( { id: 3 } ) // => "/resource/3"
```